# How to get the language code back from a localizedString?

Tags: swift, swiftui, localization

I have a Picker in my Settings tab that displays all the supported languages to the user. Showing the language codes is not very human-readable, so I display the `localizedString`s in the Picker instead. I need to retrieve the original language code back from this `localizedString`, however, to store it in the `UserDefault` (or in this case, through the `@AppStorage`). Is there a way to do this through `Locale` (or any other built-in library)? I read the documentation and tried looking for similar questions on StackOverflow / the Apple developer forum, but all questions seem to be about language code --> `localizedString`, rather than `localizedString` -> language code. Alternatively, I can also make an enum that stores all this information for me, but I'd like to know whether there's a better way of doing this.

The code:

```swift
@AppStorage("language") var language: String = "en"
@State var selectedLanguage = "English"

Picker("settingsTabGeneralSectionHeader".localized(), selection: $selectedLanguage) {
    ForEach(Bundle.main.localizations, id: \.self) {
        Text((Locale.current as NSLocale).localizedString(forLanguageCode: $0)!)
    }
}
.onChange(of: selectedLanguage) { selection in
    language = ??? // Inverse of Locale.localizedString
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can bind `Picker` selection directly to `AppStorage` and use code as tag to match, so code is simplified to

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("language") var language: String = "en"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected: " + language)
            Picker("", selection: $language) {
                ForEach(Bundle.main.localizations, id: \.self) {
                    Text((Locale.current as NSLocale)
                      .localizedString(forLanguageCode: $0)!).tag($0)  // << here !!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and selection separated from presentation.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestLocalizationPicker.swift)